# What is the simplest method to get a stream from a string

Tags: .net

Is there an accepted idiom or a quick and simple way to get a stream representation of a string?

Or is my best bet a `new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(myStr))` where `myStr` is some string variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want UTF8, then yes the code shown in the question is entirely correct.

The only thing I would change is: consider whether your API should actually be talking about `TextReader` rather than `Stream`. If so, `new StringReader(myStr)` would do nicely.

But for arbitrary binary `Stream` usage, your code is correct as shown (especially if you add a `using`, although in reality that is moot since for `MemoryStream` it is a no-op `Dispose()`; but I'm fussy ;p)

Comment: Well, I think I may be mistaken about the encoding there - it really should be `Encoding.Unicode` :$